# IProgressMonitor as a parameter in eclipse plugin programming

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, progressmonitor

I see a lot of eclipse plugin APIs that have `IProgressMonitor` as one of its parameters.

```
void setRawClasspath(IClasspathEntry[] entries, IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws JavaModelException;
```

1. What is this IProgressMonitor for? Do you have any good example?
2. Is it OK to pass `null` to it? Or do I have to create and pass an object (`new ProgressMonitor()`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `IProgressMonitor` provides ways for the callee to report progress, rather than just status, to the caller.  You can find examples in the article at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html , as well as its use throughout the Eclipse SDK.

2) `null` is only ever OK if the JavaDoc for that method says it is.  Otherwise the assumption should be that it is not.  The `NullProgressMonitor` implementation is of use in cases where `null` is forbidden but you still need to provide one.